# Server name/IP remove in SVN URL keywords

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use tortoise for svn. I want to update svn info by svn:keywords in my project files.

By adding this line to the respective file,

```
Repository path:    $HeadURL$
```

And adding "HeadURL" in the file tortoise properties(svn:keywords), I can show the URL of the svn in the server:

```
Repository path:    $HeadURL: http://svnserver.com/svn/aliaspooryorik/trunk/Application.cfc $
```

My question is that, how can I remove the server name/IP in the URL, like:

```
Repository path:    $HeadURL: /svn/aliaspooryorik/trunk/Application.cfc $
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found, if I update the version of client svn program (tortoise), then I'm able to take advantage of new features in keywords.

That is, simply replaced "URL" with "URL=%P" in the keyword configuration, then I have just the address of the file instead of the full URL.

E.g:

```
trunk/sampledir/samplefile.txt
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/svn/projname/trunk/sampledir/samplefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A URL by definition requires a scheme (the `http://` part) and a "scheme specific part" (the full path, including server name). Without these two pieces of information, the `HeadURL` would be quite meaningless (and not a URL).

If you really need this, I would suggest not processing keywords (use `svn export --ignore-keywords`), or post-processing your files to strip those portions out.

Comment: Would you please give a more clearly solution if I'm really not able to use keywords to generate not the full path, but the path without server name?

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by that. `svn:keywords` isn't very flexible, so if you want to retain the path but drop the scheme & server portions of the URL, you'll have to run a process that modifies each of those files to strip that content out.

Comment: Since, this HeadURL generated by keywords to the files which would be used by customers later on, We prefer not to show our server name for some security reasons, but we would like to know the path of the file in our svn server.
So, would you please give me a hint or link for further information that how can I run such a process to strip the servername out.

Comment: Stripping the link out is a fairly simple exercise in text processing. You should have a programmer on staff who is capable of writing something to do it.

Comment: Assume that a script is written, then how this file can be run right after the keywords are executed?

Comment: Keywords aren't "executed". They are processed by the Subversion client as part of the checkout/export/update process. You would need to include the script in your process that prepares your product for distribution to the customer (insert that script into the process wherever you've still got the files available, before compiling or zipping). You should have a programmer on staff who is capable of doing this, assuming you already have a well-defined build/package/deploy/distribution process (and if you don't, that's a completely separate issue your team needs to address).